# Retrieve Package_Data from SSIS DB

Tags: sql-server, ssis, package, integration

I need to find all SSIS packages deployed on SQL Server with a certain script in it. So I am trying to search the Package_Data column on SSISDB -> Internal.packages .

The trouble I am facing is that the Package_data column is Null on this table.

I used to use this approach with msdb.dbo.sysssispackages to list out all package containing a certain 'text' and was attempting the same approach on SSIS DB and realized this column is null.

Can anyone please advise:
1.  A Way to retrieve Package_Data from SSIS DB? 
2.  Why the Package_data field is null on the SSIS DB ?

Thank you

Comment: I had the same problem to find the xml data with PowerShell. I ended up in downloading (http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2016/04/get-packages-from-ssis-catalog.html) and extracting the IsPacs to search (http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2016/02/searching-in-packages-with-powershell.html) within the XML